# How to feed path variables into CMake?

Tags: variables, cmake

What's the best way to provide external information like library paths (i.e. BOOST_ROOT) to my CMake scripts so I don't have to hardcode them inside my script files or clutter my system with environment variables?

I can only think of a user config file where all the paths and additional variables are stored as CMake variables and which is then included by CMake. Is there anything better than that or is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You listed pretty much all the options.

I personally like to provide two mechanisms for the user to provide paths to find scripts, one via environment variables and one via CMake variables:

```
find_library(FOO_LIB foo PATHS $ENV{FOO_PATH} ${FOO_PATH})
```

Now the user can decide: If they prefer environment variables, they set `FOO_PATH` in the environment. If they prefer config files, they can store the path there and pass it to CMake through the command line:

```
cmake -DFOO_PATH=/path/to/foo ../path/to/source
```

If they prefer to use the CMake GUI, they can create the `FOO_PATH` variable there.

It's a simple mechanism that provides a maximum of flexibility to the user.